# implicit declaration of function C mysql

Tags: mysql, c, oop

```
typedef struct database
{
    char *host;
    char *user;
    char *pass;
    char *name;

    MYSQL *mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
}database_t;
extern database_t db;
```

........................

```
MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(database_t db)
{   
    //MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
    db.mysql = mysql_init(NULL);

    printf("HOST %s\n", db.host);
    if(!mysql_real_connect(db.mysql, db.host, db.user, db.pass, db.name, 0, 0, 0)) 
    {
        printf("Conection error : %s\n", mysql_error(db.mysql));
        exit(1);
    }
    return db.mysql;
}

MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connect, char *command)
{
    if(mysql_query(connect, command))
    {
        printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(connect));
        exit(1);
    }

    return mysql_use_result(connect);
}
```

.........................

if i try use mysql function in

```
int some_func()
{
  database_t *db = malloc(sizeof(database_t));
  db->mysql = mysql_connection_setup();
  return 0;
}
```

After compile il see some warnings.

*warning: implicit declaration of function 'mysql_connection_setup' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]   db->mysql = mysql_connection_setup();
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]   db->mysql = mysql_connection_setup();*

What me do whith it?

Comment: You forgot ton #include some header files.

Comment: I dont think so, all includes working right.

Answer (score 3):

The warnings say that the compiler hasn't seen any declaration for `mysql_connection_setup()` when you first use it. So, the compiler declared one implcitly with `int` return type which conflicts with your actual function. (Note that the "implicit int" rule has been removed from the C standard since C99).

So, provide a declaration at the top of your source file:

```
MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(database_t db);
```

Or declare it as `extern` in a header file and include that header file in your source files if you are using `mysql_connection_setup()` is in other source file(s).

con_setup.h:

```
#ifndef CON_SETUP_H
#define CON_SETUP_H

extern MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(database_t db);

#endif
```

and include `con_setup.h` in your C files.

Comment: If compilation is successful now and you get a segfault then you probably have other problems in your code. Run your code under a debugger.